# What is the difference between EDA (Explorative Data Analysis) and Data Profiling?

Tags: exploratory-data-analysis

I am a little confused here, seems like both use same/similar techniques. Is here a difference at all or it is the same??

Can someone clarify? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both are synonyms – terms used for the application of statistical techniques to identify patterns such as anomalies, missing values, nature of variables, etc., in underlying data. It is typically the step within a machine learning pipeline which suceeds data cleaning and precedes data preparation.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite correct, because the (clear, detailed) descriptions of data profiling at sites like https://www.ibm.com/topics/data-profiling indicate that although it overlaps a little with EDA, it has different aims and uses different techniques.  Briefly, EDA is about getting insight from data while data profiling is about assessing and managing data quality.